# create dictionary class for storing Passwords

Tags: c#, .net, passwords

I am trying to create a dictionary in C# in order to store passwords.

Could you please help me. I am new to this and Stuck. I am trying to create

```
public class PasswordPool
{
    static void Passwords()
    {
        ICollection<KeyValuePair<String, String>> openWith =
            new Dictionary<String, String>();

        openWith.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("User1", "Password"));
        openWith.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("User2", "Password"));
        openWith.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("User3", "Password"));

    }
}
```

This code does not look good to me. Could you please let me know what is missing

Comment: "Does not look good" is not a proper problem description. Explain what you expect this to do, what it does do, what you think is the issue and what you have tried to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are some issues here.

1. What is the reason for `Passwords` to be static and private (if class member doesn't has explicit access modifier - it will be private)? Since it is private - you can't use it outside of `PasswordPool` class.
2. You're creating your dictionary each time in `Passwords` method, but since it is local method variable - it is useless outside of this method. Also since `Passwords` method doesn't returns anything and does nothig with this dictionary - it is useless.
3. `ICollection<KeyValuePair<String, String>>` do you really need it? Why don't simply `Dictionary<string, string>`?

If I understood your goal correctly and you're trying to create some class storing passwords and need some static method to access them then you can try something like this:

```
public class PasswordPool
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _Passwords;

    private static void InitPasswords()
    {
        _Passwords = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        _Passwords.Add("User1", "Password");
        _Passwords.Add("User2", "Password");
        _Passwords.Add("User3", "Password");
    }

    public static string GetPassword(string userName)
    {
        if (_Passwords == null)
            InitPasswords();

        string password;

        if (_Passwords.TryGetValue(userName, out password))
            return password;

        // handle case when password for specified userName not found
        // Throw some exception or just return null

        return null;
    }
}
```

Here dictionary is private member of the class so it is accessible from any method of `PasswordPool` and `GetPassword` is public static method allowing to get password by username.